# Comparing timestamps of backup files and erasing the oldest one

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have developed a backup shell script that basically copies a file to another directory and appends to it a timestamp that, glued together, makes up a number.

Something to this effect.

```
cp file1 directory/{file1##*/} - {date +'%Y%m%d%H%M%S'}
```

Now, imagine I have 'file1 - 20151009141528' and many other file1 backups. How do I compare them and erase the one whose date makes up the smallest number?

This is honestly my last resort. I've tried and tried but to no avail!

Many thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I wanted to go for something like

```
for item in "$directory1"
do
 if *number of file1 - 20151009141528 is smaller than all remaining backup files, remove*
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just sort them by timestamp using using sort like that `sort -k3 -r` and display just the last one using tail `tail -n 1`. Did it help you?

Comment: It didn't but its my fault really. I don't know how to insert that on my script, truth be told, since I've never used tail or sort.

Comment: `ls | sort -k3 -r | tail -n 1 | xargs rm` This will remove file with smallest number.

Answer (score 0):

You can run this command: `ls|sort -V |head -n 1 |xargs rm` in the directory where you backup files located. It sorts your files then picks up the one in head and remove it. This command does not care whether the file is oldest one or newest one. It deletes the smallest based on the `sort`. If you want to run it in your script. just navigate to your directory then run the command. somthing like :

```
cd /path/to/directory;
ls|sort -V |head -n 1 |xargs rm;
```